# A way/module to display a list of Blocks assigned to specific path?

Tags: 7, blocks

OK, this is a bit tricky to explain, but I hope you understand what I'm looking for.

I have a lot of nodes created with the 'Basic page' content type, and at least 20 different blocks assigned to each Basic page. I'm wondering whether there is a way (or a module) the display a list of Blocks in the Drupal backend that are ONLY assigned to one node? There are 20 blocks assigned to each Basic page, and lots of Basic pages, therefore it is tricky to identify which Blocks are displayed on which page with the huge list I see in the Drupal Blocks page.

What would be good is if there was a way to filter Blocks on the admin page by path that they are set to, or something like that?

This is what I'm looking for, is there a module?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure have I understand your question.

At the picture below you can set it two path. Exmaple:

Page_1

Admin_Block_Page

Another one will be:

Page_2

Admin_Block_Page

When you go to Admin_Block_Page, it will display block in Page one and Block in Page two.

[image]

Another Method: views
Module:https://www.drupal.org/project/views
You tube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L9JLZOb_LQ